# Recogniz the power of two of an integer

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a number and it is power of 2. (example: 2^k)
i want to obtain the value of k without using loop ,division or any kind of function?
bit operation, plus, subtract, condition can be used.
Some help please if you have any algorithm or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a number and it is power of 2. (example: 2^k) i want to obtain the value of k without using loop

Some MIPS CPUs have a `CLZ` instruction for counting the number of leading zeroes. If you invert the result from that instruction you get the index of the first set bit.

If you don't have a `CLZ` instruction you can achieve the same thing in the following manner. There might be more compact implementations, but this is at least a branch-less implementation for finding the log2 of an integer (it's a variant of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set)):

```
# The number to find log2 of
li $t0,512

li   $t1,0      
li   $t2,0xFFFF0000
and  $t3,$t2,$t0
sltu $t4,$zero,$t3  # if (($t0 & 0xFFFF0000) == 0) {
xori $t4,$t4,1
sll  $t4,$t4,4  
addu $t1,$t1,$t4      # $t1 += 16
sllv $t0,$t0,$t4      # $t0 <<= 16 }
sll  $t2,$t2,8   # $t2 = 0xFF000000
and  $t3,$t2,$t0
sltu $t4,$zero,$t3  # if (($t0 & 0xFF000000) == 0) {
xori $t4,$t4,1
sll  $t4,$t4,3
addu $t1,$t1,$t4
sllv $t0,$t0,$t4
sll  $t2,$t2,4
and  $t3,$t2,$t0
sltu $t4,$zero,$t3  # if (($t0 & 0xF0000000) == 0) {
xori $t4,$t4,1
sll  $t4,$t4,2
addu $t1,$t1,$t4
sllv $t0,$t0,$t4
sll  $t2,$t2,2
and  $t3,$t2,$t0
sltu $t4,$zero,$t3  # if (($t0 & 0xC0000000) == 0) {
xori $t4,$t4,1
sll  $t4,$t4,1
addu $t1,$t1,$t4
sllv $t0,$t0,$t4
sll  $t2,$t2,1
and  $t3,$t2,$t0
sltu $t4,$zero,$t3  # if (($t0 & 0x80000000) == 0) {
xori $t4,$t4,1
addu $t1,$t1,$t4
xori $t0,$t1,31     # $t1 holds the number of leading zeroes; invert to get the highest set bit
# The output is in $t0
```

Comment: Instead of this code it's probably simpler to use a lookup table with 32 entries.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not allowed to use loops, if I may ask? Is this a class project where you're being told to do it in a particular way? If not, a loop would be so much easier to code and simpler to understand:

```
.text
# The number to find log2 of
li $t0,512

add $t1, $zero, $zero # init counter with 2^0
addi $t2, $zero, 1 # init mask

loop:
and $t3, $t0, $t2 # mask all but current bit
bne $t3, $zero, done

# Current bit of $t1 is zero. Look at the next one to the left.
sll $t2, $t2, 1  # shift mask
addi $t1, $t1, 1 # bump counter
j loop

done:
# $t1 contains power of 2 (original number = 2^$t1)
```

Caveats: this code doesn't check whether it really is a power of 2, and it's an endless loop for 0! Those validations are left as an exercise for the student. :)